# [material-ui][DatePicker] Change @material-ui/pickers Ok/Cancel dialog buttons text color for DatePicker/TimePicker/DateTimePicker

Tags: reactjs, datepicker, material-ui

Is there any way to change the text color for the Ok/Cancel dialog buttons from the @material-ui/pickers DatePicker/TimePicker/DateTimePicker? I have managed to change other elements using overrides, but cannot find the theme selectors for the bottom buttons.

Here is a code sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-pickers-411qz?file=/demo.js

I tried using:

- MuiDialogActions in the createMuiTheme, but cannot select the buttons, only the panel gets styled
- withStyles for the buttons for DatePicker
- a separate ThemeProvider for different flat button styling for TimePicker

None worked. I would like a solution for the buttons other than changing the primary color for all elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass `cancelLabel` and `okLabel` props to change the text of the button.

For more information, https://material-ui-pickers.dev/api/DatePicker scroll down to `Modal Wrapper` section.

Comment: Thank you! I missed that part where you could add a react node for the buttons.

I have also updated the code sandbox for DatePicker and all I needed to do was provide custom `span`s for the okLabel and cancelLabel.
`okLabel={<span style={{ color: "#304257" }}>Ok</span>}`

`cancelLabel={<span style={{ color: "#304257" }}>Cancel</span>}`

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work anymore with version 5

Comment: @Kevin Gilbert, did you find a solution for new version?

Comment: @tannerman I was looking for a solution to change the text and I found props `cancelText` and `okText`.

Answer (score 0):

I was using `okText` and `cancelText` props but they got removed. I found an easy way to change the translations of these buttons on your MUI Theme.

```js
createTheme (
  {
    //...
  },
  {
    components: {
      MuiLocalizationProvider: {
        defaultProps: {
          localeText: {
            cancelButtonLabel: 'My custom cancel button label',
          },
        },
      },
    },
  }
)
```